# Remove stale buffers after switching to a different branch

Tags: magit, buffers, git

This is the scenario:

1. Switch to a new git branch
2. Open some "new files" in that branch
3. Switch back to an older branch that doesn't have these "new files"
4. I want these opened buffers for these not any more existent files purged

How to do that?
I tried `(recentf-cleanup)` but that didn't work.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with `recentf`, but I could be wrong. `recentf` just keeps track of files you've accessed recently with Emacs. And its cleanup just cleans up its list of those files. It has nothing to do with GIT, as far as I know. Also, deleting buffers that visit files has no effect on the files.

Comment: You are correct. recentf is not related. I was just mentioning what I tried so far. I just want a quick way to discard buffers for files that don't exist anymore (in the current branch).

Comment: The title talks about removing *files*. Please edit the question to make clear what you're requesting.

Comment: Done. Thanks for pointing the out.